# Error Running Endeca baseline update

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

**Endeca baseline update fails on my machine**

**when tracing logs ,found the following in CRS.0.0.log**

```
Jun 24, 2015 9:40:25 AM com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller execute
SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'BaselineUpdate'. Releasing locks.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.invokeRequestedMethod(Controller.java:917)
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.execute(Controller.java:255)
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.main(Controller.java:134)
Caused by: com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException: Error executing valid BeanShell script.
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.runBeanShellScript(Script.java:179)
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.run(Script.java:127)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacComponentControlException: Batch component  'Dgidx' failed. Refer to component logs in C:\Endeca\Apps\CRS\config\script\..\..\.\logs\dgidxs\Dgidx on host ITLHost.
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.component.BatchComponent.run(BatchComponent.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHIfStatement.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.runBeanShellScript(Script.java:165)
    ... 8 more
Jun 24, 2015 9:40:25 AM com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.base.LockManager releaseLock
INFO: Released lock 'update_lock'.
```

**and when referring to Dgidx log as mentioned in the above error I found the following error in Dgidx.start.log:**

```
WARN    06/24/15 07:40:24.242 UTC (1435131624242)   DGIDX   {dgidx,baseline}    Notice: the '--tmpdir' option has been deprecated; see the product documentation for more details.  

usage: dgidx [--compoundDimSearch] [--cov]
             [--diacritic-folding] [--help] [--lang <language id>]
             [--nostrictattrs] [--numbins]
             [--out <stdout/stderr file>]
             [--sort <spec>[|(asc|desc)]]
             [--spellmode <spelling mode>] [--spellnum]
             [--stemming-updates <file>] [--threads <num>]
             [--version]
             <data export file> <output db_prefix>

  -q   Quiet mode.
  -v   Verbose mode.

  --compoundDimSearch   Enable compound dimension search for the
                        application. Use of this option increases indexing
                        time. But if this option is not enabled at index
                        time, compound dimension search results (multiple-
                        dimension value results) will not be returned by
                        the ENE.
  --cov                 Compute and report coverage statistics for
                        dimensions and properties.
  --diacritic-folding   Ignore character accents when indexing text.
  --help                Print this help message and exit.
  --lang <lang id>      Default to the specified language for all documents.
                        Default to the specified language/collation for mdex queries.
                        Specified in the format: 'LANGUAGE-u-co-COLLATION'
                        (default=en-u-co-endeca)
  --nostrictattrs       Disable strict attribute checking. Allows records
                        to retain property values for properties with no
                        <PROP_REF> element defined in the navigation
                        configuration file.
  --numbins <num>       Limit the number of records that the indexer reads.
  --out                 Specify file path to which stdout/stderr should be.
                        remapped (default is to use default stdout/stderr
                        for the process).
  --sort <spec>[|(asc|desc)]   Specify a default sort specification (spec)
                        for the data set.
  --spellmode           Specify the spelling correction mode for the
                        application. Supported modes are "default",
                        "aspell", "espell", "aspell_OR_espell", and
                        "aspell_AND_espell".
  --spellnum            In spelling modes that enable the "espell"
                        module, include non-word terms (numbers, symbols,
                        etc.) in the espell dictionary. By default, such
                        terms are not included.
  --stemming-updates <file> Updates the default stemming dictionary
                        according to specified file.
  --threads <num>       Specify the number of threads to use for the
                        multi-threaded portion of the indexing process.
                        The default is 1.
  --version             Print version information and exit.

**FATAL 06/24/15 07:40:24.242 UTC (1435131624242)   DGIDX   {dgidx,baseline}    Unrecognized option 'C:\Endeca\Apps\CRS\data\dgidx_output\CRS'**
```

Endeca is installed and configured using CIM.

Thanks

Comment: Please can you update your question with the specific ATG and Endeca versions that you are using, and include the `ConfigurationGeneratorForge.start.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed after found incorrect configuration parameters in /Endeca/apps/CRS/config/script/DataIngest.xml

I've specified the following parameters inside this file.

```
<properties>

  <property name="numLogBackups" value="10" />

  <property name="numIndexBackups" value="3" />

</properties>

<args>

  <arg>-v</arg>

  <arg>--compoundDimSearch</arg>

  <arg>--lang</arg>

  <arg>${LANGUAGE_ID}</arg>

  <arg>--spellmode</arg>

  <arg>aspell_AND_espell</arg>

</args>

<log-dir>./logs/dgidxs/Dgidx</log-dir>

<input-dir>./data/forge_output</input-dir>

<output-dir>./data/dgidx_output</output-dir>

<temp-dir>./data/temp</temp-dir>

<run-aspell>true</run-aspell>
```

with the missing --spellmode
after adding the missing argument , issue resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the solution to your problem can be found [here](http://edgydebug.blogspot.mx/2015/06/resolving-batch-component.html). I encountered this problem with ATG 10.2.0.3 and Endeca 3.1.2.  One of the Endeca configurations, `environment.properties` is referencing the incorrect version of the record store forge adapter.